# Symfony UniqueEntity for two Fields doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, unique-constraint

I want to use an Unique entity over the fields companyID and personMailaddress.
When I use just the personMail in the fields it works without any problems. But when I add another field to the array, like below, it ignores my  UniqueEntity.

```
/**
 * person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\personRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity( 
 *          fields={"personMail", "companyID"},
 *          errorPath="personMail", 
 *          message="ERROR_MAIL_DUPLICATE",
 * )
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class person
{
   ... 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="company", inversedBy="persons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    protected $companyID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="personMail", type="string", length=150)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="ERROR_MAIL_EMPTY")
     * 
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    private $personMail;
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable unique you need to add the `UniqueEntity` validator and add `unique` to the column definition.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\personRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity( 
 *          fields={"personMail", "companyID"},
 *          errorPath="personMail", 
 *          message="ERROR_MAIL_DUPLICATE",
 * )
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class person
{
   ... 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="companyId", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="company", inversedBy="persons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    protected $companyID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="personMail", type="string", length=150,  unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="ERROR_MAIL_EMPTY")
     * 
     * @Serializer\Expose
     */
    private $personMail;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't wrote it in my question. But I already insert: use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;